# How code generation works for Ait-Kaci's WAM L1?

Tags: prolog, warren-abstract-machine

[Hassan Aït-Kaci's "Warren's Abstract Machine: A Tutorial Reconstruction"](http://wambook.sourceforge.net/) Section 2.4 extends L0 to L1 in order to support a set of facts in the abstract machine. The four new instructions `put_variable`, `put_value`, `get_variable` and `get_value` have arguments `Xn` and `Ai`, whose meanings are not clear. The description only mentions index `i` of argument `Ai`: the `i`-th argument position of the predicate. Where `n` of `Xn` comes from? Figure 2.9 presents an example of generated code for query `p(Z,h(Z,W),f(W))`. Since predicate `p` has arity 3 and the first instruction is `put_variable X4, A1`, `n` can't be the predicate's arity.

Comment: *Too much is left untold, ...* says the author in the introduction about the original paper, and now well, the biggest critics of the elves later become elves themselves.

Comment: In 2.4 nevertheless, it is explained that `Ai `is just a *conspicuous* notation  for `Xi` when the register is meant as an argument register.  So `X4` is an auxiliary scratch register, the next free register. The `put_variable X4, A1` thus means: Make both register 4 and register 1 point to the same variable.